# Why do we need "closed" here?

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces

There is a statement such that: Every closed finite co-dimensional subspace of a Banach space is complemented.

I don't really see why we need the subspace to be closed. If $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is a finite co-dimensional subspace of $X$. Then $X/Y$ is of finite dimension thus a Banach space. So the canonical map $X \to X/Y$ is a surjective continuous linear map, thus the kernel $Y$ is complemented. What's wrong with this argument?

Comment: Thanks. But I already figured it out. The answer that I was searching is that $Y$ has to be closed to make $X/Y$ actually a normed vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer that I was searching is that $Y$ has to be closed to make $X/Y$ actually a normed vector space.

I somehow did not find this answer satisfying. Let's consider an example. Let $f:X\to \mathbb R$ be a discontinuous linear functional on $ X$ (over real  scalars).  The space $Y=\ker f$ has codimension $1$. So, $X/Y$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, and one can define    a norm on $\mathbb R$ in various ways.

The issue is not with $X/Y$ itself, but with the projection map $X\mapsto X\setminus Y$. Since the kernel of this map is $Y$, it cannot be continuous unless $Y$ is closed.

Comment: nice point! Thanks for point that out.